# Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-developers-console

Giving error even I enabled Google+ API in Google Developers Console

> Code:403  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."

Answer (score 21):

You have **not** enabled the `Google+ API` for your project in the `Google Developer console`.   Make sure that its enabled and double check that your code is using the correct `client`_id and `clientsecret`, that match this project.  My tutorial on [how to enable APIs in Google Developers console.](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-apis/)

**Where to enable it:**

Go to the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0)  on the left look for the Apis & Auths menu under that you will find the API menu.

> APIs & auth -> API

Look for Google+ API enable it.

Comment: I don't know if the page changed, but I found I needed to go to this page to enable API  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/plus.googleapis.com?q=Google%20plus&project=hbuniversaltest&folder&organizationId   (Make sure to select the right project you want to update)

Answer (score 7):

I found there to be about a 30 minute delay between enabling the API and it allowing me to make calls.

To speed this up I needed to run an API explorer query like this:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/calendar/v3/calendar.calendarList.list

But it may have been a coincidence :)

Comment: I was also seeing the same error, ran a query in the api explorer, specifically [this one](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=me&_h=1&), and then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks man, Great tip. Was flpping around wondering why it won't work